# How to connecting firebase from php?

Tags: php, firebase

Hello i am trying to make connection to firebase database from php and i have this code

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__ . '/secret/sajilo-entrance-med-firebase-adminsdk-1bta4-487ebfe276.json');
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount);
$firebase = (new Factory)
->withServiceAccount('$serviceAccount')
->withDatabaseUri('https://sajilo-entrance-med.firebaseio.com/')
->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

?>
```

and i am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Kreait\Firebase\Factory::withServiceAccount() must be an instance of Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\MedEntrance\dbconfig.php on line 10 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\MedEntrance\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Factory.php:77 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MedEntrance\dbconfig.php(10): Kreait\Firebase\Factory->withServiceAccount('$serviceAccount') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MedEntrance\insert_test.php(43): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MedEntrance\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Factory.php on line 77

Comment: Have you checked what `$serviceAccount` contains? It seems to be a string while `Factory::withServiceAccount()` expects an instance of the `ServiceAccount` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try change `withServiceAccount('$serviceAccount')` to `withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)`